# mkdir error in react.js while creating react.js app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mern

i got this error message while executing npx create-react-app my-app

npm ERR! code UNKNOWN

npm ERR! syscall mkdir

npm ERR! path C:\Users\Saad\AppData\Local\npm-cache_cacache\content-v2\sha512\1b\f2

npm ERR! errno UNKNOWN

npm ERR! Invalid response body while trying to fetch http://registry.npmjs.org/native-url: UNKNOWN: unknown error, mkdir 'C:\Users\Saad\AppData\Local\npm-cache_cacache\content-v2\sha512\1b\f2'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Saad\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2021-04-19T07_11_18_894Z-debug.log

Comment: Check the log C:\Users\Saad\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2021-04-19T07_11_18_894Z-debug.log you might find the detailed error there

Answer (score 1):

1-Remove directory  C:\Users\Saad\AppData\Local\npm-cache_cacache\content-v2\sha512\1b\f2

2-run npm install again

this method worked for me